# Make each span element farther from rest, except one

Tags: css, less

I want to be able to write a style in less, where I can apply it to 4 span tags. I want each span to have all the same properties, but I want to have be 30px; of space between each one. An finally, I want the 2nd span to have a different distance from the right than all the others.

Is there a way to do this, or do you need to write a separate style for span 2?

So here is my style for each span, which works fine. But there must be a better way with less...??

```
.right-lines {
  z-index:100; 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:80px; 
  height:2px; 
  background-color:#fff; 
  right:-80px; 
  margin:40px;
  top:140px;
}

.right-lines2 {
  z-index:100; 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:80px; 
  height:2px; 
  background-color:#fff; 
  right:-50px; 
  margin:40px;
  top:180px;
}

.right-lines3 {
  z-index:100; 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:80px; 
  height:2px; 
  background-color:#fff; 
  right:-80px; 
  margin:40px;
  top:220px;
}

.right-lines4 {
  z-index:100; 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:80px; 
  height:2px; 
  background-color:#fff; 
  right:-80px; 
  margin:40px;
  top:260px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the lines to be 30px from one another, use 30px of margin. There is no need for so much absolute positioning. This also allows for fewer specific styles.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.right-lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.right-lines span {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 80px 30px auto;
 }

.right-lines span:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.right-lines span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-lines">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a common class or use the span tag itself to style the common features. You can, of course get even more efficient with other class stylings. And a sample span tag might look like `<span class="span_class right-lines">...</span>`

```
/* common styles */
.span_class {
    z-index:100; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:80px; 
    height:2px; 
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:40px;
}

/* And now make the special ones */
.right-lines {
    right:-50px;
    top:180px;
}

.right-lines2 {
    right:-50px; 
    top:180px;
}

.right-lines3 {
    right:-80px; 
    top:220px;
}

.right-lines4 {
    right:-80px; 
    top:260px;
}
```